# Delete id from array in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following Mongoose Schema

```
 var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    createdOn: {type: Date, default:Date.now },
    purchaseDate:Date,
    expiryDate:Date,
    isEnabled: {type: Boolean,default: true},
    messages:[{
        message: String,
        location: String,
        date: Date,
    }]
});
```

When I convert document to JSON, I want to get rid of `_id` of each message inside messages array. My current toJSON method is below

```
UserScheme.methods.toJSON = function() {
    var obj = this.toObject();
    delete obj._id;
    delete obj.__v;
    return obj;
};
```

Comment: So what is question?

Comment: How can I get rid of ```_id``` of each item inside messages array? I can prevent generating id field by using _id : false but I want to hide it from JSON.

Comment: Then just add `obj.messages = obj.messages.map(function(el) { delete el._id; return el; })` inside the `toJSON` method. It's probably not a wise idea to remove `_id` in either case, since they are in fact the unique identifiers for either the main object or those in the array, and are very useful for that exact purpose.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn I want to get rid of from JSON output only. Because although they are array, they only make sense together. I don't need to query single message. I put this example just for quick mockup.